# function only returning last cor() value

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I'm using the cor() function within a for loop. For some reason it only outputs the last value in the for loop, the rest are displayed as NA. below is my code. I have a directory with 300 or so csv files regarding air quality. My function is designed to sift through the directory for csv files with a certain number of complete cases within its data. Then it will compute the correlation between 2 variables in each csv file and output it in the variable storage .threshold is a parameter designed to only take a data file that have  over a certain number of complete cases.

```
    corr <- function(path = "/Users/jeffreystreit/Downloads/specdata", threshold = 0){
  
  setwd("~/")
  setwd(path)
  
  storage <- vector()
  
  files<- list.files()
  names(files) <- 1:331
  
  data <- complete()
  data<- subset(data, nobs>200)
  data<- data$id
 
 for(i in length(data)){
   x <- data[i]
   data2<- read.csv(files[x])
   storage[i] <-  cor(x= data2$nitrate,y= data2$sulfate, use ="pairwise.complete.obs")
 }
 return(storage)
  }
```

example of output: (why does only the last one show a value and the rest are NA?)

```
  NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
[10]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
[19]        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
[28]        NA        NA        NA 0.2687805
```

helper method: converts csv files into list of #of complete cases. if the number of csv files doesn't exceed the threshold value it will be excluded.

```
complete <- function(path="/Users/jeffreystreit/Downloads/specdata", id = 1:332){
  
  setwd("~/")
  setwd(path)
  
  files<- list.files()
  names(files) <- id
  
 nobs<-vector()
  

    for(i in id){
    data<- read.csv(files[i])
    data<- data[complete.cases(data),]
    nobs <- c(nobs,nrow(data))
    }
  
    frame <- data.frame(id,nobs)
 
}
```

Comment: What error messages do you get when you run this code? You seem to have two functions where a single one would be more efficient. Write a function to read the data from a single file and then compute the correlation if the number of observations is sufficient. Then use that function with `sapply` or `lapply` to process all of the files.

Comment: 1) The function assigns the result to `frame` but does not return it, the last instruction is the return value so it should be a code line with just `frame` (or, equivalently, `return(frame)`); 2) don't set the wd in a function, please.

Comment: In the first function instead of `length(data)` try `seq_along(data)`.

Comment: seq_along() fixed the problem, thanks Rui! and I agree dcarlson it would be more efficient to have one function instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, both functions read the files, a time consuming operation. And there is an error in the `for` loop,  instead of `length(data)` it should be `seq_along(data)`.

The function below computes and returns the correlation between nitrate and sulfate reading the files only once and without calling an auxiliary function `complete`.

Untested, since we do not have access to the files.

```
corr <- function(path = "/Users/jeffreystreit/Downloads/specdata", min.obs = 200L){
  
  if(is.null(path)) path <- "~/"
  files <- list.files(path = path, full.names = TRUE)
  nfiles <- length(files)

  nobs <- integer(nfiles)
  storage <- numeric(nfiles)

  for(i in seq_along(files)){
    data <- read.csv(files[i])
    data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
    nobs[i] <- nrow(data)
    storage[i] <- cor(x = data$nitrate, y = data$sulfate, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
  }
  
  storage <- storage[nobs > min.obs]
  return(storage)
}
```